# Magento change default column layout

Tags: magento

Ok I've checked everywhere including here and everyone's answers is exactly what I have written down so I have no idea why it's not working.
I cleared Magento's cache besides the configuration..

This is what I have in my local.xml file:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <!-- Remove callouts and rarely used stuff -->
        <remove name="right.poll" />
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout" />

        <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
            <!-- Add the local stylesheet -->

            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I deleted the other css stuff I had written since my only concern is the root reference.
My directories look like:

- simplistic

  - layout

    - local.xml
  - template

    - page

      - html

        - footer.phtml
        - header.phtml
        - etc (all other layout subthings)
      - 1column.phtml

What exactly am I doing wrong? It's still using the 2 column layout when I'm trying to make it use the 1 column..

EDIT:

For anyone curious on the page, here is the page:
http://magento.neofill.com/magento/

You would think after editing local.xml in the default, that would affect all pages right? I don't get what I'm doing wrong. I keep searching and everything is exactly the way I have it. It should be working but if you view the source code, you'll see that it's using the 2 column layout here:

```
<div class="main-container col2-right-layout">
```

Comment: You sure that the page you're trying to show doesn't have a layout update for its specific route ? (in XML or in backend)

Comment: I just installed this magento installation like an hour ago so I doubt that's it.. But how do you check for that just in case? I have nothing in the backend showing something needs updated.

Comment: I added more information to the OP

Comment: Yeah like I said you were trying to change default settings that were overriden by page specific ones ;)